# помогите решить задачу на (Python)

Tags: python

Текстовый файл состоит из символов A, B, C, D, E.

Определите максимальное число идущих подряд символов в файле, удовлетворяющих условию: среди выбранных символов не встречается символа “A”, который идёт раньше символа “B”.

Например, подряд идущие символы “BCBAD” подходят под это условие, а последовательность символов “DCACBB” - не подходит. Для выполнения этого задания следует написать программу.

Начало файла 24.txt

CDBABBEBEB...

я решил задачу так

```
   def max_sequence(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
    max_len = 0
    current_len = 0
    for i in range(len(data) - 1):
        if data[i] == 'A' and data[i + 1] == 'B' and (i + 2 < len(data) and data[i + 2] == 'B'):
            current_len = 0
        else:
            current_len += 1
        if current_len > max_len:
            max_len = current_len
    return max_len

print(max_sequence('24.txt'))
```

но это решение не верное. Помогите решить задачу

Comment: Не совсем понятен второй пример -- ведь в последовательности `DCACBB` существует префикс `DCAC`, для которого выполняется указанное условие, значит максимальная длина в этом случае получается равной 4.  Аналогично в файле, начинающемся с последовательности `CDBABBEB...`, максимальная длина тоже будет 4: `CDBA`.

Answer (score 2):

Расстояние между `A` и `B` может быть любым, поэтому проверки вида `data[i + 1] == 'B'` естественно не будут работать.

Алгоритм по идее должен быть такой:

- Используете три указателя - на начало последовательности, на встреченную последней букву `A` и на текущий обрабатываемый символ
- Когда натыкаетесь на `A` в очередной раз, то запоминаете в указатель на `A` её позицию (пока `A` не уйдёт из "окна" весь кусок до `B` будет нам бесполезен)
- Когда натыкаетесь на `B`, то сдвигаете указатель начала на символ после этой `A` (см. примечание выше, этот бесполезный кусок стал актуальным)
- В остальных случаях если длина между текущим указателем и начальным больше текущего максимума, запоминаете её в максимуме
- Ну и увеличиваете позицию конца на 1
- И так пока строка не закончится

Там ещё будут детали инициализации, проверок на конец строки и т.д., но в целом это алгоритм сложности `O(n)`, потому что правый указатель всё время двигается вперёд и никаких циклов внутри нет, только отдельные действия по условиям.

Comment: Спасибо это сработало